# Thread Sleep from new thread not adding a delay

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to show an initial splash window for like 4 seconds and proceed to the next window i.e. NextGenDGRunSetupWindow in my case. So just to mimic those 4 seconds to show the Splash screen I am starting a new thread and saying Thread.Sleep(4000); on the new thread. But the problem is when I run the application I don't see anything for 4 seconds and the NextGenDGRunSetupWindow window is starting up. How can i add a delay on the new thread and show my splash screen before going to the next window. Please see the CheckIsInstrumentReadyToRun() method in the view model.

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class SplashViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _showLoadingDisplay;
        public bool ShowLoadingDisplay
        {
            get
            {
                return _showLoadingDisplay;
            }
            set
            {
                _showLoadingDisplay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowLoadingDisplay");
            }
        }

        public event Action<InstrumentStateEnum> CanProceedFurtherAction;

        private static SplashViewModel _instance;
        public static SplashViewModel SplashViewModelInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new SplashViewModel();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        public SplashViewModel()
        {
            ShowLoadingDisplay = true;
        }

        public void CheckIsInstrumentReadyToRun()
        {
            //JUST TO MIMIC SOMETHING IS HAPPENING STARTING A NEW THREAD AND THAT ONE WAITS
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CallFirmaware));
            t1.Start();
            var value = InstrumentStateEnum.Loading;
            t1.Join();
            //Fire the event
            CanProceedFurtherAction?.Invoke(value);
        }

        public void CallFirmaware()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Code behind

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Window
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SplashViewModel splashViewModel = SplashViewModel.SplashViewModelInstance;
            this.DataContext = splashViewModel;
            splashViewModel.CanProceedFurtherAction += SplashViewModel_CanProceedFurtherAction;
            splashViewModel.CheckIsInstrumentReadyToRun();
        }

        private void SplashViewModel_CanProceedFurtherAction(BioRad.NextGenDG.Model.Shared.InstrumentStateEnum obj)
        {
            if (obj == BioRad.NextGenDG.Model.Shared.InstrumentStateEnum.Loading)
            {
                NextGenDGRunSetupWindow SetUpWindow = new NextGenDGRunSetupWindow();
                SetUpWindow.Show();
            }
            this.Close();
            //ERROR OCCURRED TAKE TO SOMEWHERE
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread.  Don't do that.  You should use `Task` and `await` instead of threads.

Comment: I also tried using Task t1 = Task.Run(() => CallFirmaware());
   Task.WaitAll(t1);
An in  the Call Firmware I am saying Task.Delay(4000); but still it dosen't help.

Comment: `Task.Wait` still blocks the UI thread.  You need to use `await`.

Comment: It sounds like a bad user experience anyway. At least let the user dismiss or even turn off that splash screen.

Comment: Ok I changed my CallFirmware() method as follows public async void CallFirmaware()
  {
   await Task.Delay(4000);
  }
And to Call that method I am saying var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallFirmaware());
   t.Wait();
But still no change in behaviour.

Comment: Yes for now it is bad. But in the future I will be calling some middleware that internally talks to the firmware. The firmware to boot up and get things going it hits some delay. I just want to mimic that delay for now

Comment: It does no good whatsoever to create a thread, and then block the _current_ thread waiting for the other thread to finish. You might as well just do the work in the current thread if you're going to do that. We have no shortage of _working_ examples of splash screens and background processing on Stack Overflow. I suggest you use the search feature and do some research.

Comment: @Wouter: you seem confused. You can start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Note the very first piece of advice: _"[Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search), and research"_. Then, you might also read the rest of the articles at https://stackoverflow.com/help/. If there were anything wrong with asking questions per se, Stack Overflow wouldn't exist. It's the asking of questions that have already been answered, failing to research, or failing to demonstrate said research, that's wrong.

Comment: @Wouter: _"people helping each other to find the answer is a very powerful concept"_ -- that's a naïve way to look at it. Fact is, helping people who don't provide good quality questions just encourages more bad quality questions. We are drowning in those as it is. This is not the place for your idealistic, unblemished altruism. _"the referenced duplicate answers should be up to date with current language features and be of high educational quality"_ -- feel free to post a suitable answer on the marked duplicates. That's where such answers would belong.